Problems installing packages for R in Ubuntu possibly related to non-writable folder
I installed and ran R in Ubuntu, including several files.
However, problems arose when I needed the package tidyverse. Judging from what I know now, it is not the only package with issues installing.
When I try to install it, it goes over a 10 minute routine of trying to download and install dependencies, and eventually gives me an error message.


If I try to install the dependencies separately, I also run into problems.
I wonder if the issue can be troubleshot by understanding the first warning and two questions that I am asked at the very beginning:
Warning in install.packages("tidyverse") : 'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
and
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) y Would you like to create a personal library ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ to install packages into? (yes/No/cancel) y
I never faced this issue with Windows, and I have no idea what it means. I have tried uninstalling Ubuntu, and re-installing R.
Incidentally, I have Python installed without issues.
I tried going into R as sudo R - no difference.

Of note, I was able to install psych:



Solved! In case it helps anyone... I was taken by surprised since I never experienced these issues with prior Ubuntu and R installations, but it all seems to stem from WSL needing updating. All woes are gone now with the following steps:
First going to Windows + R and unchecking the option of a Subsystem for Linux, 
rebooting and checking the option again. 

Then from within Ubuntu, running, `wsl.exe --update`. 

Finally, some remaining messages around the output of `library(tidyverse)` 
were ironed out by running in R `install.packages("devtools")` 
and `devtools::install_github("r-lib/conflicted")`.


Did you still get an error after you you choose "y" to create a personal library? That's how most package should be installed. Otherwise what't the exact error message you are getting? Most likely you are missing some dependency for a package you are trying to install. We'd need to see the complete output of install.packages() to know whats really going on.

As you are installing packages for yourself (as user), therefore 'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable is saying, that user has no write rights to /usr/local/... which is fine. And system proposes to install it in user ~/... directory, which is fine as well, because in Ubuntu the installed packages are kept in '~/R/....directory.~means/home/user/`. On the other hand Windows "doesn't care" about permissions, or per default user has Administrator rights, so can write almost everywhere.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko and @MrFlick I answer 'yes' to both questions. And I did try once to make that directory writable by going in there with sudo R, but it didn't work. Yes, it is my laptop (100 percent). Are you saying that the message is expected, and that I answered 'yes' correctly? What can I do next?

if you answered y(es), do you have something in ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ folder?

@GrzegorzSapijaszko I just installed without a glitch the package psych. See OP.

I don't see any problems or error here. It looks like the package installed fine. You should use personal libraries and avoid running R with sudo. You just get a message the first time if a personal library doesn't exist. It's not an error.

@MrFlick That helps. Why is it having issues with some packages?

What "issues"? What packages? It's hard to tell without any details.

@MrFlick I posted a capture in the OP. Thank you!

Please do not post error message in images. Most likely there's a message right above that error that you cut out that shows what system dependencies you are missing and how to install them. Check for a section called "ANTICONF" in the output.

I am posting it now in OP. I wish I had time now to type it. I will later.

As MrFlick mentioned, the exact cause of the issue — and how to fix it — is shown in the very first screenshot.

In the first screenshot there is a sentence: Configuration failed to find ... library. Try instaling: deb libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev.... So, in your case (Ubuntu uses deb packages) open a terminal and run sudo apt install libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev ... (add any required library). It should help at least for {textshaping}. On the other hand, you can try $ sudo apt install r-cran-textshaping, it should install library system-wide (including all dependencies), but I haven't used it for long time (I mean to install r packages via apt).

@GrzegorzSapijaszko I almost got tidyverse installed... It's "there" now... Listed, and callable with library(tidyverse, but with a lingering error: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down. Could you help me decipher this?

I have installed Ubuntu and R in at least 5 or 6 PC's, and never run into these issues. Could it be a WSL problem? Is there a way to repair WSL?

Cma'n, never seen that :). But I don't use WSL..https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate - does it help?

@GrzegorzSapijaszko Yes, it does! I have solved the issue by first going to Windows + R and unchecking the option of a Subsystem for Linux, rebooting and checking the option again. Then from within Ubuntu, running, wsl.exe --update. Finally, some remaining messages around the output of library(tidyverse) were ironed out by running in R install.packages("devtools") and devtools::install_github("r-lib/conflicted").

Glad you solved it. Would you mind to collect all the issues and describe the solutions for them, one by one? As an answer to your question. Not now, but in free time. It may help others in the future.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko Absolutely. Since this is one of those "dear in the headlights" or "silly" questions, but still likely to help other people at the same level of disorientation, I included the fixes in the OP. I figured it wasn't worth a formal answer...
